# Seperate Space delimited word and remove duplicate words

Tags: php, cpu-word, unique, explode

I found **preg_split** and **explode** functions in php for breaking space seperated string into words. its quite useful too. but the next step i would like to work is remove the duplicate words and [",","." and few other punctuation marks ] too...

like if
"**I love nepal. Nepal is a landlocked country. Nepal is in Asia.**"

I would like to get only unique words in the sentance like:
**I, love, nepal, is, a, landlocked, country, in, Asia**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

This should just about get the job done:

```
$string = "I love nepal. Nepal is a landlocked country. Nepal is in Asia.";
$string = preg_replace( "/[^\w\s]/", "", $string );

$words = array();
foreach ( explode( " ", $string ) AS $word ) {
    $word = strtolower($word);
    $words[$word] = 1;
}

$unique_words = array_keys( $words );
```